# Banner or Billboard or Other

Tags: vocabulary

I want to know that what is the name of things that are installed above the entrance of the shops (Banner or Billboard or ...)? I need this word to google it for getting some related images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to what are generally called  ***[shop signs](https://www.google.it/search?q=shop%20signs&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIT608IT616&hl=it&prmd=ismvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiltoKk9JjQAhVhIcAKHeUlAY4Q_AUIBygB&biw=320&bih=492)***

[Sign](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sign):

> - A displayed structure bearing lettering or symbols, used to identify or advertise a place of business.

AHD

Comment: Or possibly [store-front signs](https://www.google.it/search?q=store+front+signs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1920&bih=960) [the *store front* is the whole caboodle, window and all]

Answer (score 0):

***Signage*** - Signs collectively, esp. commercial signs or those on public display; the design and arrangement of these. Orig. U.S. (OED).